# Rails routing with a has many through relationship, no id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, many-to-many, nested-routes

So I have a bands table, a festivals table and a bands_festivals table. I am having trouble accesing the show page of the bands_festivals table.
This is my routes file:

```
Ejemplo::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :bands_festivals 

  resources :festivals do  
    resources :band_festivals   
  end 

  resources :bands do  
    resources :band_festivals
  end
```

As other people suggested, but I still get the following error:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"band_festivals", :id=>#'<'BandFestival band_id: 2, festival_id: 1, year: 1, created_at: "2013-11-20 19:24:38", updated_at: "2013-11-20 19:24:38">}

If you would like to look at my controllers they are here: [The "create new entry" page on a many-to-many-relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022693/the-create-new-entry-page-on-a-many-to-many-relationship)

Comment: What are you doing before you get that error?  Clicking on a link, I assume?  If so, what's that `link_to` tag look like?

Comment: I am accessing localhost:3000/band_festivals. That is the index page for the band_festivals table, where it should show me all my created entries for that table

Answer (score 1):

Well your error says there is no route for controller=>"band**a**_festivals" but your routes is drawing for band**s**_festivals like CDub your link may have typo.

Comment: no, thats not it. I just translated everything to english from spanish, and forgot a word. The mistake isn't there. I already edited the output to match the translation

Answer (score 1):

Your routes has no `band_festivals` path which isn't namespaced below either `festivals` or `bands`.  You'll either need to:

a. Change your routes such that you'll have `resources :band_festivals`...

or

b. Change your view to access the band festivals via `bands_festivals`.